# Isn't 'int GetHashCode' a bit short-sighted?

Tags: .net, hashcode

Given that .Net has the ability to detect bitness via IntPtr (looking through reflector a good amount of it is marked unsafe, though - shame) I've been thinking that GetHashCode returning an int is potentially short-sighted.

I know that ultimately with a good hashing algorithm the billions of permutations offered by Int32 are absolutely adequate, but even so, the narrower the possible set of hashes the slower hashed key lookups are as more linear searching will be required.

Equally - am I the only one who finds this amusing:

```
struct Int64{
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return (((int) this) ^ ((int) (this >> 0x20)));
  }
}
```

Whilst Int32 simply returns `this`.

If IntPtr is out of question because of performance concerns, perhaps an IHashCode that implements IEquatable etc is better?

As our platforms get larger and larger in terms of memory capacity, disk size etc, surely the days of 32 bit hashes being enough are potentially numbered?

Or is it simply the case that the overhead involved in either abstracting out the hash via interfaces, or adapting the size of the hash according to the platform outweighs any potential performance benefits?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Int64 hash function is there to make sure that all the bits are considered - so basically it is XORing the top 32 bits with the bottom 32 bits. I can't really imagine a better general-purpose one. (Truncating to Int32 would be no good - how could you then properly hash 64-bit values which had all zeros in the lower 32 bits?)

If IntPtr were used as the hash return value, then code would have to have conditional branches (is it 32-bit? is it 64-bit? etc), which would slow down the hash functions, defeating the whole point.

I would say that if you have a hashtable which actually has 2 billion buckets, you're probably at the stage of writing an entire custom system anyway. (Possibly a database would be a better choice?) At that size, making sure the buckets were filled evenly would be a more pressing concern. (In other words, a better hash function would probably pay more dividends than a larger number of buckets).

There would be nothing to stop you implementing a base class which did have an equivalent 64-bit hash function, if you did want a multi-gigabyte map in memory. You'd have to write your own Dictionary equivalent however.

Comment: yes I understand that ^ing them together makes sure all the bits get considered - makes a lot of sense. Interestingly, if you look at IntPtr - used for things like method handles - it simply truncates to an int. That's great if you've got handles to data in the upper 32 bits of memory and you're using them for keys!
I take your point about conditional branching - you couldn't make the 32-bit/64-bit hash transparent to the code that generates it.  I also take your point about writing a new data structure to store more data - which I guess is where you would ultimately have to take it.

Comment: I can easily imagine a better one. A key characteristic of a good hash is full avalanche, meaning that a change in any input bit will flip half the output bits, on average. XOR-ing the two halves produces no avalanche at all. See [here](http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/inthash.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You *do* realize that the hash code returned by `GetHashCode` is used for addressing in a hash table? Using a bigger data type would be a futile exercise since all hash tables are smaller anyway. Additional information would simply be wasted because it cannot be used adequately.

Common hash tables have in the order of a few thousand to a few million entries. A 32 bit integer is more than sufficient to cover this range of indices.

Comment: Well - that's not quite true - a hashcode of 2,034,242,111 doesn't get used as an index . Unlike an array, there is nothing other memory restricts a hashtable in size - theoretically there's no reason it couldn't have 10 billion elements, even with a 32 bit hash. It's just memory restrictions. Bring on a machine with couple of hundred gigs of ram (okay, let's say a terabyte) and we could fill it with such a huge hashtable. Wheher you would - or create some other structure, however - is another story!

Comment: @Andras: how is that any different from a normal array (hint: it isn’t). And yes, you *could* have 10 billion elements – just as with a normal array but that just doesn’t scale on *any* current architecture. Convolving the whole .NET architecture for the *one* machine worldwide that can handle 1 TeB of main memory doesn’t sound like a good trade-off to me. The point is: architectures necessarily involve trade-offs and doubling the size of an address may be a big deal.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, you do understand however that a hash function with a greater range will give much better collision resistance, i.e. way less .Equals calls. Of course the hash, may it be 16bit or 32 or 64 is ` mod some prime greater than capacity`, still the distribution of the hash function matters here.

Comment: @SebastianGodelet Unless your hash table has > 2^32 buckets (very uncommon!) that plays no role whatsoever. See my previous comment which makes much the same point.

Comment: If you have two different lets say `Length > 32` strings A and B, the chance they will have a hash collision is a magnitude higher with 32bit than with 64bit, no matter the size of the hash table. What I mean with collision is that two different input strings yield the same hash code. If the hash code is the same, the bucket size becomes irrelevant. The better the hash function is distributed the less `bucket collisions` will occur within the hash table, even for sizes smaller than 4 billion

Comment: @SebastianGodelet But the hash value collision is irrelevant for the hash table implementation. What’s relevant is the actual hash table *index* collision. We’re only interested in that final result.

Comment: Reducing hash value collisions is the *key* to a good hash table performance. If too many values collide in their hash values, your hash table will quickly degrade to the performance of a linked list.

Comment: I'm not good at math, but the comment in this link says it all:
http://kenneththorman.blogspot.de/2010/09/c-net-equals-and-gethashcode.html

Comment: @Sebastian The article you linked is completely unrelated to hash tables. All it shows is that the author has never heard of the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox), and was consequently using hash codes wrongly. And you are right about reducing collisions is key to a good hash table but like I said before,  we are only concerned about collisions in the *final* hash (i.e. after scaling down to the hash table size), not collisions of the *preliminary* hash. A 32 bit hash will collide more often than a 64 bit hash but we are using *neither* in a hash table.